# Replace every occurence of a letter by multiple other letters

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function in Rust that takes a string and outputs a vector of strings, which are "copies" of the input string, but with every "X" replaced by every digit.

That is to say, my function "replace_combination" will take "aXb" and output "a0b", "a1b", ..., "a9b".

This same function will also take "aXbX" and output "a0b0", "a0b1", ..., "a0b9", "a1b0", ..., "a1b9", ... "a9b9" (100 elements).

I'm thinking of writing a recursive function, I've tried the following code:

```
fn every_combination(hand: &str) -> Vec<&String> {
    let mut combinations: Vec<_> = vec![hand.to_string()];

    while let Some(j_index) = combinations.last().unwrap().find('J') {
        let mut new_combinations = Vec::new();

        for digit in '0'..='9' {
            for existing in &combinations {
                let mut new_string = existing.clone();
                new_string.replace_range(j_index..j_index + 1, &digit.to_string());
                new_combinations.push(&new_string);
            }
        }

        combinations = new_combinations;
    }

    combinations
}
```

but I get the following error for the last `combinations` line:

> mismatched types
> expected struct `Vec<&String>`
> found struct `Vec<String>`

(plus I'm not very found of "for" and "while" loops in Rust, I'd like a more "elegant" function)

Comment: You can't return a reference (`&String`) to a value you create inside the function (`String`)

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Make your function return `Vec<String>` and follow the suggestions in the rust compiler output from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `Vec<String>` instead and push without the reference:

```rust
fn every_combination(hand: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut combinations: Vec<_> = vec![hand.to_string()];

    while let Some(j_index) = combinations.last().unwrap().find('J') {
        let mut new_combinations = Vec::new();

        for digit in '0'..='9' {
            for existing in &combinations {
                let mut new_string = existing.clone();
                new_string.replace_range(j_index..j_index + 1, &digit.to_string());
                new_combinations.push(new_string);
            }
        }

        combinations = new_combinations;
    }

    combinations
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would have loved a functional/recursive version, but that will do!